# Log Cat not displaying anything?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

**Log Cat** is not displaying anything in my ADT Tools ?
What is the issue ?
I have tried testing on both emulator and my Original Device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already:

1. try unplugging your device, plugging it back in
2. Clicking the Devices tab in eclipse
3. If you see your device click it, then open log cat's view
4. If you don't see it, try restarting eclipse.

This can happen if its been plugged in for a long time etc, I've read that ADT is HORRIBLE with long running development sessions especially if your dev computer went to sleep and was re-awakened.